# boton no redirecciona a la seccion del header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, botón

No logro que el buton de "hace tu pedido" redireccione a la sección de "Productos" del header. Ya intente con <a href o pasándole propiedades del tab.
Esta realizado con tab pills de bootstrap 5
adjunto imagen y codigo html, si alguien me puede dar una mano por favor

actualizo subo codigo del header y el button al que quiero que redirecion a Productos

```
<!-- menu hecho con tabs -->
<header class="container-fluid bg-dark position-sticky top-0">
  <ul
    class="nav nav-pills mb-3 py-3 container bg-dark"
    id="pills-tab"
    role="tablist"
  >
    
    <!-- quiero que el boton redirecione a esta tab -->
    <li class="nav-item text-primary" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="pills-home-tab"
        data-bs-toggle="pill"
        data-bs-target="#pills-home"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-home"
        aria-selected="true"
        >Home</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link active"
        id="pills-profile-tab"
        data-bs-toggle="pill"
        data-bs-target="#pills-profile"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-profile"
        aria-selected="false"
        >Productos</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="pills-contact-tab"
        data-bs-toggle="pill"
        data-bs-target="#pills-contact"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-contact"
        aria-selected="false"
        >Carrito</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<button class="btn btn-primary button" href="pills-profile-tab">
          Hace Tu Pedido
        </button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te falta integrar la ruta del archivo con `href` ejemplo `href="producto.html"`

Comment: Es un <a href=""....> siempre bro... https://i.gyazo.com/dd983381542c0412b2cc77ab21b8380f.gif

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta, que tu mismo dices que es a href... pero no pones el href...

Comment: @ivan, podrías publicar todo el código para que sea mas fácil ayudarte? Solo hay una parte de código y no es suficiente.

Comment: creo que esta tratando de hacer un menú basado en tab, y que se vaya cargando abajo sin necesidad de crear rutas a archivos, el botón de abajo no va tener efecto ya que no tiene los datos de dicho item que activa el tab, @ivan por favor sube el código almenos del botón ese que tratas redireccionar!

Comment: Exacto Daniel, el menu estaba en tab y no se que valor poner para que redireccione bien ya que href en el boton no iria en este caso ya que no estaria pidiendo que vaya a otra pagina, o al menos eso creo. ahi edito con el codigo completo. Gracias

Comment: `<a id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab">Hace Tu Pedidos</a>` intenta con eso, luego dale estilo con `css` estilo botón!

Comment: @daniel no tampoco funciono y probe tambien <a class="btn btn-primary" href="pills-profile" role="button" >Pedir Ya</a> y no hay caso pd(hice la pregunta como invitado antes de crearme cuenta en stack y ahora no me deja responder jaja)

Comment: Los buttons no tienen atributo href. Si quieres que sea un enlace, conviértelo en un `a`

Answer (score 0):

Como te han comentado antes, con `button` jamás lograrás hacerlo funcionar, tienes que cambiar el tag por un `a`, que es el que permite introducir el atributo `href`.

Además, necesitas añadirle el hash (`#`) al enlace para llamar correctamente a la id: `<a href="#pills-profile-tab">`.

```css
header {
height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<!-- menu hecho con tabs -->
<header class="container-fluid bg-dark position-sticky top-0">
  <ul
    class="nav nav-pills mb-3 py-3 container bg-dark"
    id="pills-tab"
    role="tablist"
  >
    
    <!-- quiero que el boton redirecione a esta tab -->
    <li class="nav-item text-primary" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="pills-home-tab"
        data-bs-toggle="pill"
        data-bs-target="#pills-home"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-home"
        aria-selected="true"
        >Home</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link active"
        id="pills-profile-tab"
        data-bs-toggle="pill"
        data-bs-target="#pills-profile"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-profile"
        aria-selected="false"
        >Productos</a
      >
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a
        class="nav-link"
        id="pills-contact-tab"
        data-bs-toggle="pill"
        data-bs-target="#pills-contact"
        type="button"
        role="tab"
        aria-controls="pills-contact"
        aria-selected="false"
        >Carrito</a
      >
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>

<a class="btn btn-primary button" href="#pills-profile-tab">
          Hace Tu Pedido
        </a>
```

De todas formas, ten en cuenta que si no existe la suficiente distancia entre el botón y el header, no tendrá ningún efecto. El elemento al que quieres saltar debería estar fuera del viewport para que el botón te haga subir hasta él.